# Can this port be used to connect an external display to laptop?

Tags: display, multiple-monitors, port

I have a monitor attached to my laptop via HDMI and want to attach a second monitor.

In attached screenshot what type of port is below, the one to left of USB ports ?

Can it be used to connect a monitor ?

[image]

Comment: I have added a bit of information which you may perhaps find useful.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, its an ethernet port - presumably off an ultrabook (Maybe a Zenbook?). Its however got a little extendable bit so its slimmer. You can't plug a monitor into it.

You seem to have it confused with a displayport

[image]

or maybe even a mini display port

[image]

(both from [displayport/wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DisplayPort))

or maybe even HDMI - which amusingly is sometimes used for switch to switch networking

[image]

(also [via wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HDMI))

Comment: Of course, there's still the well-known VGA display. You could also find USB VGA cards easily, but that's out of the OP's question scope.

Comment: technically you could use a screen sharing software and a virtual desktop but that requires a second computer...

Answer (score 3):

You can however attach another HDMI monitor to your pc, if this is the reason behind your question. In order to do this, you may use a **USB to HDMI Converter** (also known as **Adapter**), a component which is available just about everywhere on the Internet. An example of such a converter is this:

[image]

There are even USB 3.0 models, which will give you better performance.